# Data passed to train function of a classifier in flux-Julia

Tags: dataframe, machine-learning, julia, flux.jl

It's my first time to deal with Flux package in Julia.
I have data (columns are features and rows are records).
I do not understand what loss function take(just a tuple or a data frame) and what should be the data (tuple or data frame)?

the function: `Flux.train!(loss, ps, data, opt)`

[Details are here](https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/training/training/), and [here there is an example](https://github.com/FluxML/model-zoo/blob/master/vision/mnist/mlp.jl).

I've tried to know where the problem comes and debugged on Atom IDE but can not understand what to do.

1. I've tried to transpose my data and take rows then columns as data instances but i had this error:

   > no method matching loss(::Float64)
2. I've tried to take the data frame as a whole but got this error:

   > no method matching iterate(::DataFrame)
3. I've added `(Iterators.repeated((x, y), 3))` to be the data but got this error:

   > MethodError: no method matching (::Dense{typeof(identity),TrackedArray{…,Array{Float32,2}},TrackedArray{…,Array{Float32,1}}})(::DataFrame)
4. I've tried to fix the 3 point by editing `Dense` function but did not work also.

What do you suggest?
And what should I do to understand Flux well? because the documentation of it is not enough to let me understand.

## one code trial :

```
D = DataFrame(adjoint(Matrix(data)))
X = D[1:6,: ]
Y = D[7,:]
m = Chain(Dense(7,1))
loss(x, y) = crossentropy(m(x), y)
accuracy(x, y) = mean(onecold(m(x)) .== onecold(y))
dataset = repeated((X, Y), 200)
Flux.train!(loss, Flux.params(m), dataset, ADAM())
```

got this error:

> no method matching (::Dense{typeof(identity),TrackedArray{…,Array{Float32,2}},TrackedArray{…,Array{Float32,1}}})(::DataFrame)

Comment: Can you give us some example `data` so we can run your code snippet and see the error ourselves?

Comment: The data is 6 features and one column for label (binary).The 6 features represent two coordinates according to different devices (x,y,z) and (x',y',z') and a label that nearly represents the position of the second device according to the first one (assume the position of it is fixed) so i train the model to predict the position ... **The error** has been fixed  when i used an array using function ' hcat(col1,col2,..) ' instead of using a data frame .. **Thank you** @Engineero ..